# Installing m4 which requires autoconf

Tags: configure, autoconf, m4

I downloaded `m4` from [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/m4.html). In the `INSTALL` it is said that I should first `./configure`. But to do that, if I understood correctly, I need to generate `configure` via `autoconf` from `configure.ac`. I do not have `autoconf` so I downloaded it from [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/autoconf.html). The problem is that I need `m4` to build `autoconf`. Seems like they depend on each other. How can I install `m4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the INSTALL it is said that I should first ./configure

Yes.

> But to do that, if I understood correctly, I need to generate configure via autoconf from configure.ac.

No, there's no need to do that.  The `configure` you need is in the m4 tarball.

> How can I install m4?

The old [three step](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10961439/425738): `./configure ; make ; make install;`