# Is it necessary to run ./configure every time a change is made to a MIB installation file?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

After generating the `.c` and `.h` files using *mib2c*, the next step (if I am correct) is to run *configure* which is found in `~/net-snmp/`.  This, combined with `make` and `make install`, 'register' the OID node specified by the aforementioned `.c` file.

**If a change is made to either the `.c` or `.h` files, is it necessary to go through the process again, or is there a more 'lightweight' way to apply the changes?**  `make` and `make install` tend to take a very long time.

Comment: `./configure` is [probably not needed](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/the-magic-behind-configure-make-make-install) all the time unless (guessing) you make significant changes to your MIB like importing a new one.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Do you know if that applies to net-snmp specifically or not?

Comment: Should be similar for any C app. As [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10961543/2834978), may be not needed every time. If you have a Makefile.in and it has changed then configure should be run I think.

Comment: btw, seems mib2c generates a Makefile, why do you need to run configure?

Comment: I've seen a few other users report using it, and I guess I also want to make sure that net-snmp is configured to recognize/use my subagent.  If the Makefile is unchanged by modifications to subagents, then I suppose I do not need to be running `./configure`.

Comment: I think the difference is that `./configure` builds a Makefile for *snmpd* whereas `mib2c` creates one for installing the C files? Not sure...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173227/discussion-between-luis-munoz-and-ctrl-s).